# Are there online Euclidean GCD calculators for Euclidean domains other than $\textbf Z$?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, euclidean-algorithm

There is no shortage of online calculators that will compute the GCD of two integers from $\textbf Z$.

For example, [the one from Calculator Soup](https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/math/gcf-euclids-algorithm.php), it will even show you the steps (try it with two consecutive Fibonacci numbers).

But are there any such calculators for other Euclidean domains, even if limited to a single norm-Euclidean domain? For example, a calculator that you can put in two integers from $\textbf Z[\sqrt 2]$.

Is there such a thing? Might this question encourage someone who has something like this laying around on his computer to post it on the Web?

Answer (score 4):

You can use SAGE online via https://cocalc.com/ with the commands from [Euclidean Domains](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/categories/sage/categories/euclidean_domains.html)

Comment: The same could be said about the Wolfram Cloud. Sage might not need as much new programming as the Wolfram Cloud, but it's still a long way from the Calculator Soup page Dave gave as an example. Even so, upvote from me.

Comment: I never found Wolfram to work as well for being able to control which ring you are working in. So I default as Sage for algebra, Wolfram for analysis.